# Union of an Open and Closed Set

Tags: probability, probability-theory

```
A = [6,8]
B = [2,7)
```

If A is the interval of all real numbers x such that 6 <= x <= 8 and

B is the interval of all real numbers such that 2 <= x < 7, then what would the union be?

I want to say it's `[2,6,8]` because in set B, we are not including 7, but I am not sure.

**Here is the exact question out of the textbook I am reading**:

When working with real numbers, our universal set is R. Find each of the following sets.

[6,8] union [2,7)

Comment: If $A = \{x : 6 \leq x \leq 8\}$ and $B=\{x : 2\leq x < 7 \}$. What would $A \cup B$ be? Think of what union means by definition. Also, the set $[2,6,8]$ is no longer an interval whereas $A$ and $B$ are intervals. Additionally B is not an open nor closed set but A is a closed set.

Comment: A union of two sets is a set containing all elements that are in A or in B, or both. How is B not open because it has a parenthesis on the end? Wouldn't it be closed on the left and open on the right?

Comment: What is the definition of an open set you are working with?

Comment: Just edited my original post to include it. Thank you for your patience, I am learning probability.

Comment: I don't see a definition for an open set. However, for the union you gave the correct definition so using the notion I used for $A$ and $B$, what do you get for $A\cup B$. It is not $[2,6,8]$.

Comment: The only other answer would be [2,6,7,8], no?

Comment: No, lets consider $A = \{x: 6\leq x \leq 8\}$. This set contains $6,\ldots 6.0001, 6.1, 6.2,6.9,7.1,.......,8$ Moreover, if in the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$,which it appears you are, this set contains infinitely many values in it. $B$ can be handled in a similar fashion.

Comment: [6,8] union [2,7) would be [2,6, x > 6 and x < 7, x > 7 and x <=8] 

like that?

Comment: Getting closer, but that is messy notation. I recommend revisiting definitions of closed sets, open sets, unions, intersections and look at set-builder notation.

Comment: How would you write it?

Comment: Like this?
{x: x >= 2 and x < 7, x > 7 and x <= 8}

Comment: That is still incorrect, 7 is an element of A. Union is elements of one set or the other

Comment: Didn't you just write {x: x>= 2 and x<= 8, x <> 7} ?

Comment: What does $[2,6,8]$ mean to you? I'm not familiar with this notation.

Comment: I am new/inexperienced, but it means all numbers starting (and including) 2 all the way to, and including, 8, but I'm probably using the wrong notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A = \left[6,8\right] = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R} \middle| 6 \leq x \leq 8\right\}$

$B = \left[2,7\right) = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R} \middle| 2 \leq x < 7\right\}$

Therefore, if $x \in A \cup B$, $x$ is such that $6 \leq x \leq 8$ **or** (mathematical **or**, which means *one, the other or both*) $2 \leq x < 7$, which gives $2 \leq x \leq 8$. Therefore,
$$A \cup B = \left[2,8\right] = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R} | 2 \leq x \leq 8\right\}$$

Answer (score -2):

This is how I wrote it:

$\{x:x \ge 2\text{ and }x \le 8, x <> 7\}$

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Your notation is unclear

Comment: I am new to writing this stuff, so I will explain it in English and maybe you can help me write a better version. 

"The union between sets [6,8] and [2,7) is x given that x >= 2 and x <= 8, and does not equal 7".

Comment: That help? Again, I am new to this stuff.

Comment: That’s not correct. $x$ is allowed to equal $7$. Read the other answer again carefully